# Purpose of blocks-<date> directory

Tags: nodeos

1) What is purpose of directories named:

- `blocks-2020-04-15T06:55:01.360`
- `blocks-2020-04-15T06:55:13.755`

2) What is purpose of file named:

- `portable-reversible-blocks-2020-04-15T06:55:01.407`

3) What will happen if I remove that directories and file?

Thank you!

[image: nodeos workdir tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are backup data generated during replay. If you don't have any issues in execution of nodeos, you can delete them. The current process of nodeos you run refers to "blocks" directory only.